# modify return values from Object.fromEntries

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-2019

I am trying to modify the values of an object by using `.fromEntries()`.
As you can see in the picture below, I am literally returning a modified Array of hours, but after the function ends, it returns the complete Array, instead of the updated one.

Thank you for any ideas in advance!

[image]

```
    let filteredDates = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(slots).filter(([slot, value]) => {
        let result = datesArray.some(filterdates => {
            return filterdates.some(filter => slot === filter)
        })
        let currentDay = slot === day ? value.filter(time => time >= currentHour) : null
        result = currentDay ? currentDay : result ? value : result
        console.log("result",result)
        return result
    }))
    
    console.log("filteredDates",filteredDates)
```

Comment: `filter()` doesn't return the results of the callback function. It returns the elements of the original array whenever the callback function returns a truthy value.

Comment: Use `map()` if you want to return a new array by transforming the values from the original array.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, the issue with that is I cannot return null, undefined, or false, else I am getting TypeError: Iterator value false is not an entry object

Comment: You should be returning an array of the form `[newkey, newvalue]`

Comment: If you want to return conditionally use `reduce()`, or use `.filter(testfunction).map(conversionfunction)`

Answer (score 3):

I think the closest solution to your current approach is to `map` first, returning `null` for the entries you want to delete, and then `filter` out the `null` entries to prevent `Object.fromEntries` from throwing. In code:

```js
const myObj = { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3 };

// Your modification
const doubleWithoutB = ([ key, value ]) => 
  key === "b"            // This is your filter logic
    ? null
    : [ key, value * 2 ] // Here's your map operation
    

console.log(
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object
      .entries(myObj)
      .map(doubleWithoutB)
      .filter(kvp => kvp !== null) // Get rid of the null kvps
  )
)
```

If you want to do it in one pass, you could skip `Object.fromEntries` and `reduce` the entries in to an object yourself:

```js
const myObj = { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3 };

// Your modification
const reduceDoubleWithoutB = (acc, [ key, value ]) => 
  Object.assign(
    acc,
    key === "b" 
      ? {}
      : { [key]: value * 2 }
  )
    

console.log(
  Object
    .entries(myObj)
    .reduce(reduceDoubleWithoutB, {})
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I solved it using a mix of both of your answers. I removed Object.fromEntries() and I added the .filter(kvp => kvp !== null). Now works fine. Thanks Final code:
```let filteredDates = Object.entries(slots).map(([slot, value]) => {
        let result = datesArray.some(dates => {
            return dates.some(filter => slot === filter)})

        let currentDay = slot === day ? value.filter(time => time >= currentHour) : null
        result = currentDay ? currentDay : result ? value : null
        return result
    }).filter(value => value !== null)```